# How to write function with rest/spred operator (from js) on c++?

Tags: javascript, c++, templates

How to write such function on C++?

```
function executor (foo, ...args) {
    return foo(...args)
}
```

I don't understand how to declare template on C++

Comment: `I don't understand how to declare template on C++` then your first step should search how to use templates and how they are defined. How to get something that is similar to what you can do in JavaScript also depends on your use-case. C++ and JavaScript are two different languages with different concepts and thus different approaches to solve things. rest/spread in JavaScript is done at runtime, variadic class templates and fold expressions in c++ are done at compile time so there is no one-to-one mapping between these two concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really clear to me what you are asking, or what you are trying to do.

Here's an example of an `invoke` template function that calls the passed function and passes in the arguments to the function's parameters.  That seems to be what your code snippet is trying to do.

The code is just for quick-and-dirty example.  It is not optimal, because it is not using perfect forwarding of the arguments.  Not sure what you want to do with the result of the invoked function, or handle exceptions.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
void invoke(F fn, Ts... args) {
    fn(args...);
}

void print(int a, int b) {
    cout << "print:" << a << " " << b << "\n";
}

void bigprint(int a, int b, int c) {
    cout << "bigprint:" << a << " " << b << " " << c << "\n";
}

int main() {
    invoke(print, 1, 2);
    invoke(bigprint, 1, 2, 3);
}
```